# Mail API stopped to work

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an automated java mail application that sends automated mail to users when some important update occur in our database. It was working fine. However it started to give me errors and I realized that it's not working.

The error says:
"Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 l10sm7526045oev.7 - gsmtp"

The java mail application that I write is huge and contains some confidential values(password etc.), I decided to write a sample demo to show you what's going on. It gives me the same error. Please assume that javax.MAIL API has been imported to the project. Here is what I have:

```
public class MailDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String userName = "dummyEmail@gmail.com";
        final String password = "dummyPassword";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");//Smtp server address
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");//port for the smtp server

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dummyEmail@gmail.com"));//from email address
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("dummyEmail@gmail.com"));//to email address
            message.setSubject("My first Email");//Subject of the mail
            message.setContent("<h1>This is a test email</h1>", "text/html; charset=utf-8");//Content of the mail
            Transport.send(message);//send the message
            System.out.println("Email Stiation:Done!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: _"some sort of errors "_ is not sufficient information.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  Show the actual error message and tell us at which line the error occurs.

Comment: the only error that I receive is added. Please read it again.

Comment: You are using GMail's SMTP server. In order to access it your credentials for Google must be real. Are you sure you did not change the password of your GMail account? Or that it didn't get deleted for sending spam? You should follow the link the offered and do what it says.

Comment: well the links takes me an invalid website. Also the email and password are correct. I can log in and see the mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the problem. Actually the codes are correct. It's gmail. it blocks the sign in attempts.I think that gmail thinks the attempts are not real.